# Javascript, read object from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, object

I use Ajax in javascript to call a php file with an sql query.

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('name','mobile','rating')))
    ->from('#__apicco_crew')
    ->where('loggedin = ' . 1);
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
$return = new stdClass;
$return->success = true;
$return->errorMessage = "";
$return->data['list_crew'] = $results;
$json = json_encode($return);
echo $json;
```

The resulting object in javascript is this:

```
{"success":true,"errorMessage":"","data":{"list_crew":
[{"name":"aName","mobile":"1111111111","rating":"5"},
{"name":"bName","mobile":"2222222222","rating":"5"},
{"name":"cName","mobile":"3333333333","rating":"5"}]}}
```

The question is how can i read this thing in a javascript 2 dimensional array
so I can use something like

```
myName = result[1][0];
```

Thank you

Comment: You already solved the ajax part and just want to transform the resulting javascript object into an array? Or do you want to modify the json poduced by the php server script?

Comment: the Ajax part to make the query is working fine. i don't know how to properly read the Object which is returned to me and put it in variables or an array.

Comment: So the ajax part works fine apart from where you receive the json reply? And the php part is irrelevant? Why did you include php into your question but not the ajax request, then?

Comment: The JSON provided can be accessed using `alert(result['data']['list_crew'][0]['name']);` So if you want to focus on the item number and result, I would make your variable `var results = result['data']['list_crew']`. Then you can access each as `results[0]['name']` for example

Comment: I don't know if i clearly get what you mean. As long as i get the data correctly from the php, it means that it works in the php file. Right ? The data come correctly indeed. They ARE what i want to receive. But NOT in the way i want them to be so i can process them further.

Comment: Thank you Luke Skywalker !   :)   it works.

Comment: @Psyxiatros you're welcome